# Insert multiple rows into MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
  `id` INT(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  `uuid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  `x` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
  `z` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY idx_table_x_y_z ( x, y, z )
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, I want to add one row for every combination of `x`, `y`, and `z` between the `max` and `min` values. How can I do this?

In java I would loop through every value of `x` between `xmin` and `xmax`, `y` between `ymin` and `ymax`, `z` between `zmin` and `zmax`, and then send a query with those values and the `uuid` and `name`, but for 10k queries, that uses a lot of resources.

Is there a way to make the MySQL server do this internally?

PS: I use `REPLACE INTO` syntax when I insert rows to avoid duplicates.

EDIT:
This is the exact java alternative:

```
for(int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
    for(int y = yMin; x < yMax; y++) {
        for(int z = zMin; x < zMax; z++) {
            try {
                SH.getManager().getMysqlManager().query(
                     "REPLACE INTO blocks_" + type.name + "_" + b.getWorld().getName() + "("
                     + "name, uuid, x, y, z, time) "
                     + "VALUES ( "
                     + "'" + name + "', '" + uuid + "', " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ", " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " "
                     + ");");
            } catch (final SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do the looping with the mysql server and not in java to save i/o time.

Comment: How can I improve my question?

Comment: Just do it. 10k queries should execute pretty fast.

Comment: So there is no way to do this faster? This uses too much time to run sync, and to run it async seems a bit wasted if the server could do this internally. @JBNizet

Comment: @l0lkj . . . You could make your query better by providing sample data and desired results.  The statement "add one row for every block inside a square in the world" really doesn't make sense out-of-context.

Comment: faster than what? How many times do you need to execute that database population? What time requirement do you have? Have you tried to do it the simplest way you can imagine? It shouldn't take more than a few seconds. Is that too slow?

Comment: The code runs internally on a minecraft server with a tps at 20. Therefore this execution should really not take more than 10ms, or in worst case run async. This code should be able to insert max 100k rows into the table, but every row in relative order (as in every value of x, y, and z between min and max). If I'm not making sense, tell me.
@JBNizet

Comment: As to the simplest way I can imagine, the javacode I added to the bottom of my question is the fastest way I can imagine, any way to improve that?

Comment: @l0lkj you really, really need to learn about prepared statements. They're safer, and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into mytable(name, uuid, . . .)
    select name, uuid, . . .
    from mytable
    where x between $xmin and $xmax and
          y between $ymin and $ymax;
```

If it is something like this, then you only need one query, just the right conditions.